# My Prolog version doesn't seem to know member

Tags: prolog, amzi-prolog

I'm trying out next example in Amzi! Prolog:

```
member(apple, [apple, broccoli, crackers]).
```

And the answer is no.

```
?- member(apple, [apple, broccoli, crackers]).
no
```

Is there a problem with my version? If I try the same in swipl, then it does work...

```
?- member(apple, [apple, broccoli, crackers]).
true .
```

Does Amzi! Prolog use an own implementation of Prolog?

Comment: It would appear that Amzi! Prolog doesn't have its own `member/2` predicate. Their information on lists hints at it by describing how you can write your own: http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/a11lists.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate `member/2` is not specified in the official ISO standard, although is often provided by Prolog implementations. But the implementation differs from system to system. Some provide it as a built-in predicate. Others as a library predicate. In the specific case of SWI-Prolog, and assuming the default configuration, the `member/2` predicate is defined in the module `library(lists)`, which is auto-loaded when one of its exported predicates is called. Auto-loading is, by default, silent, which often leads users to think that they are calling a built-in predicate. In the case of Amzi! Prolog, it seems that the `member/2` predicate is not built-in but you can easily define it yourself. In order to check if a given predicate is a built-in predicate, you can usually use the standard `predicate_property/2` predicate. For example, using SWI-Prolog, you get for `member/2`:

```
?- predicate_property(member(_,_), Property).
Property = interpreted ;
Property = visible ;
Property = imported_from(lists) ;
Property = file('/Users/pmoura/lib/swipl-6.5.2/library/lists.pl') ;
Property = line_count(106) ;
Property = nodebug ;
Property = number_of_clauses(1) ;
Property = number_of_rules(1) ;
false.
```

But sadly not all systems provide the standard `predicate_property/2` predicate. Prolog standardization is not, unfortunately, one of its shiny points.

Comment: `member/2` is [defined by the Prolog prologue](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#member)

Answer (score 0):

Every version of Prolog I ever used was slightly different from the others... Nice to see there's now another one to consider, ISO Prolog  :-)

I think this link has good information: http://osprey.unisa.ac.za/phorum/read.php?674,173265,173265

Comment: FYI: ISO Prolog is here since 1995 ... see [tag:iso-prolog] for more information.

Comment: Yes but that day I really needed to vent about standards  :D  http://xkcd.com/927/